# Why is $u(x_1,x_2) = x_1 x_2$ not concave?

Tags: convex-analysis

I'm struggling with determining whether a function is convex/concave and quasi-convex/quasi-concave using Hessians and Bordered Hessians respectively.

As far as I understand it, a function is convex if all Hessian determinants are larger or equal to $0$, while it is concave if this is smaller or equal to $0$. For quasi, we look at the determinants of bordered hessians, and a function is quasi convex if all determinants are larger or equal to $0$, quasiconcave if $|H_1| \geq 0$, $|H_2| \leq 0$ etc.

Is this correct?

Using this, I can see why $x_1 x_2$ is quasi-concave, but it seems to me that it is concave as well. The Hessian is: 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &1 \\
1 &0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so $H_1 = 0$, $H_2 = -1$, hence concave?

What's going wrong?

Cheers,
Calcer

Comment: Consider $u$ restricted to the line $x_1=x_2$.

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$u( t(0,1)+(1-t)(1,0) ) = u(1-t,t) = t(1-t)$$

$$tu(0,1)+(1-t)u(1,0) = 0$$

So clearly, there exists $t=\frac{1}{2}$ such that

$$u( t(0,1)+(1-t)(1,0) ) < tu(0,1)+(1-t)u(1,0)$$

So $u$ is not concave (by the definition of concavity).

Answer (score 1):

If you look along the line $x_1 = x_2$ you will see the function is actually convex along this line for $x_1 \geq 0$. As far as 'what's going on', your Hessian is negative-semidefinite, not negative definite. When you have semidefinite instead of definite, you can't draw any global conclusions about convexity or concavity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is the reason that the above goes wrong due to the fact that the function u is not twice differentiable?

Comment: @Calcer No, your function is smooth and twice differentiable. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Second_derivative_test where they state that a convex/concave function has positive/negative semidefinite Hessian, but the converse is only guaranteed to be true if you have strict positive/negative definite Hessian -- semidefinite is not always enough, as you have found.

Comment: Thanks. My lecture notes say: a function is concave iff the second derivative is everywhere negative semi-definite. Is this incorrect then?